# Joining a table with itself

Tags: doctrine, symfony

Im trying to write a doctrine query to find all `Skill`'s where the parent_id is that of a given `Skill`.

This is the sql that would accomplish what I want:

```
SELECT *
FROM skill s1  
JOIN skill s2 on s2.parent_id = s1.id
WHERE s1.name = "somename"
```

Here's what I have so far using the doctrine query builder:

```
$childCategories = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Skill")
    ->createQueryBuilder("s1")
    ->join("AppBundle:Skill", "s2", "WITH", "s2.parent = s1.id")
    ->where("s1.name = :parentName")
    ->setParameter("parentName", "somename")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

But I'm not getting any results, what is the correct doctrine query?

EDIT: this is my doctrine orm table structure:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Skill:
type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 100
            unique: true
    manyToOne:
        parent:
            nullable: true
            targetEntity: Skill
            joinColumn:
                name: parent_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: Do you get nonempty result with original sql?

Comment: Yes, my original sql gives me the desired results.

Comment: Show mapping for AppBundle:Skill, pls

Comment: updated question ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching for related entities means that you need to add criteria that compare entities with each other (your query compares an entity with an id):

```
$childCategories = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Skill")
    ->createQueryBuilder("s1")
    ->join("AppBundle:Skill", "s2", "WITH", "s2.parent = s1")
    ->where("s1.name = :parentName")
    ->setParameter("parentName", "somename")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: Ah thank you my goodman! You may very well have saved my bum, gratitude!